Why is running coroutines sequentially different from nesting them?
This code working how expected (structured concurrency not wirking from SupervisorJob) and we will see "after delay"
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, ex ->
        Log.e("coroutine", "exceptionHandler exeption is $ex")
    }
    val customScope = CoroutineScope(Job())
    val superScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler)

    customScope.launch {

        superScope.launch {
            launch {
                Log.e("coroutine", "before delay context is $coroutineContext")
                delay(5000)
                Log.e("coroutine", "after delay")
            }
        }

        superScope.launch {
            launch {
                Log.e("coroutine", "RuntimeException coming context is $coroutineContext")
                delay(3000)
                throw RuntimeException()
            }
        }
    }

but in that consistent launch code not working and we will not see "after delay"
     val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, ex ->
        Log.e("coroutine", "exceptionHandler exeption is $ex")
    }
    val customScope = CoroutineScope(Job())
    val superScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler)

    customScope.launch {

        superScope.launch {

            launch {
                Log.e("coroutine", "before delay context is $coroutineContext")
                delay(5000)
                Log.e("coroutine", "after delay")
            }

            launch {
                Log.e("coroutine", "RuntimeException coming context is $coroutineContext")
                delay(3000)
                throw RuntimeException()
            }
        }
    }

If we specify the context its working again
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, ex ->
        Log.e("coroutine", "exceptionHandler exeption is $ex")
    }
    val customScope = CoroutineScope(Job())
    val superScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler)

    customScope.launch {

        superScope.launch {

            launch {
                Log.e("coroutine", "before delay context is $coroutineContext")
                delay(5000)
                Log.e("coroutine", "after delay")
            }

            launch (superScope.coroutineContext){
                Log.e("coroutine", "RuntimeException coming context is $coroutineContext")
                delay(3000)
                throw RuntimeException()
            }
        }
    }

Why consistent launch (with same hierarchy level) not the same as nested?
I thought that coroutine context is a parent context + its job and that case consistent launch have same context how nested one.
UPD: I think I understand how it works. In a coroutine tree rooted at SupervisorJob, if an error occurs in some branch, it kills that branch to the root.
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, ex ->
        Log.e("coroutine", "exceptionHandler exeption is $ex")
    }
    val customScope = CoroutineScope(Job())
    val superScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler)

    customScope.launch {

        superScope.launch {
            launch {
                Log.e("coroutine", "error branch try take result")
                delay(5000)
                Log.e("coroutine", "RESULT")
            }

            launch {
                launch {
                    delay(3000)
                    Log.e("coroutine", "error branch take some result of other branch")
                }
            }

            launch {
                launch {
                    launch {
                        Log.e("coroutine", "error branch RuntimeException coming")
                        delay(4000)
                        throw RuntimeException()
                    }
                }
            }

            delay(2000)
            Log.e("coroutine", "error branch take some result from start branch")
        }

        superScope.launch {
            launch {
                Log.e("coroutine", "NOT error branch try take result")
                delay(5000)
                Log.e("coroutine", "RESULT from not error branch")
            }
        }
    }


Special handling in supervisor scope applies to its direct children only, not to grandchildren.

@broot but in all my examples they are grandchildren? Or its not? They all have same hierarchy.  I don't understand that

In your first example supervisor has 2 direct children, so errors don't propagate between them. In your first example there is only one child. Let me ask you another question: why do you expect to see "after delay" if you failed the coroutine before it got to this line?

The SupervisorJob() only affects direct children.
In your first example you have two coroutines which have the SupervisorJob as their parent, namely the both coroutines started with superScope.launch. That's why failing one of them doesn't affect the other.
In your second example there is only one coroutine started with superScope.launch. It is the only direct child of the SupervisorJob. The two coroutines that are launched as that child's children are not direct children of the SupervisorJob. When one of them fails the normal behavior applys: The direct parent and the siblings ("after delay") are cancelled. Then the cancellation is propagated up the hierarchy and the superScope is notified of the cancellation of one of its children. Since it has a SupervisorJob it will not propagate the cancellation to its other children - but that doesn't matter because there are no other children.
In your third example you only start one coroutine with superScope.launch, but you also launch the failing coroutine with the superScope's context. That contains the SupervisorJob so that new coroutine now is also a direct child of the SupervisorJob. When this coroutine fails the other coroutine (started with superScope.launch) therefore keeps running.
Also see this other question I recently answered, it is closely related: Coroutine fails despite parent's SupervisorJob()

I don't think I understood what direct means. In all my examples I have a chain JobScope.laucnh  -> SupervisorScope.laucnh  -> laucnh -> launch. I don't understand how the same hierarchy can be both direct and non-direct?

@Makc I'm not sure why you think the hierarchy is the same. It is clearly not. In one example you have a single child and inside 2 grandchildren (e.g.: AA, AB) and in the second you have two children with 1 grandchildren each (AA, BA). Errors don't propagate between children, but they propagate between grandchildren. So they propagate from AA to AB, but they can't propagate from AA to BA.

In a hierarchy a node is a direct child when it is directly connected to its parent. For example, you are a direct child of your father, but you are only indirectly related to your grandfather. The same applies to coroutines: Every scope and every launch is a node in the hierarchy. superScope.launch therefore starts a coroutine that is a child of superScope. Similarly, launch { launch {} } is a hierarchy where the inner coroutine is a child of the outer coroutine. SupervisorJob only affects direct children, so coroutines further removed are not affected by it.

The construct superScope.launch { launch {}; launch {} } in your second example is a hierarchy three levels deep: superScope is the parent of the outer launch, and the outer launch is the parent of the two inner launches. The inner launches are therefore not direct children of superScope (they are grandchildren). That's the reason they are not affected by the SupervisorJob and failing one will cancel the other.
